# vue-apollo 3.0.0 Beta configuration

Tags: javascript, vue.js, graphql, apollo-client, vue-apollo

Pretty new at this so any help much appreciated. 
I know how to do Authentication with Apollo client but when I add to my Vue-cli-3 generated project the new vue-apollo-plugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-apollo). I don't understand how and where to configure my authMiddleware.

Here is the auto generated file form the the cli:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueApollo from 'vue-apollo'
import { createApolloClient, restartWebsockets } from 'vue-cli-plugin-apollo/graphql-client'

// Install the vue plugin
Vue.use(VueApollo)

// Name of the localStorage item
const AUTH_TOKEN = 'apollo-token'

// Config
const defaultOptions = {
  httpEndpoint: process.env.VUE_APP_GRAPHQL_HTTP || 'http://localhost:4000',  // Use `null` to disable subscriptions
  wsEndpoint: process.env.VUE_APP_GRAPHQL_WS || 'ws://localhost:4000',
  // LocalStorage token
  tokenName: AUTH_TOKEN,
  // Enable Automatic Query persisting with Apollo Engine
  persisting: false,
  // Use websockets for everything (no HTTP)
  // You need to pass a `wsEndpoint` for this to work
  websocketsOnly: false,
  // Is being rendered on the server?
  ssr: false,

  // Additional ApolloClient options
  // apollo: { ... }

  // Client local data (see apollo-link-state)
  // clientState: { resolvers: { ... }, defaults: { ... } }
}

// Call this in the Vue app file
export function createProvider (options = {}) {
  // Create apollo client
  const { apolloClient, wsClient } = createApolloClient({
    ...defaultOptions,
    ...options,
  })
  apolloClient.wsClient = wsClient

  // Create vue apollo provider
  const apolloProvider = new VueApollo({
    defaultClient: apolloClient,
    defaultOptions: {
      $query: {
        // fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
      },
    },
    errorHandler (error) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      console.log('%cError', 'background: red; color: white; padding: 2px 4px; border-radius: 3px; font-weight: bold;', error.message)
      },
  })

  return apolloProvider
}

// Manually call this when user log in
export async function onLogin (apolloClient, token) {
  localStorage.setItem(AUTH_TOKEN, token)
  if (apolloClient.wsClient) restartWebsockets(apolloClient.wsClient)
  try {
    await apolloClient.resetStore()
  } catch (e) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log('%cError on cache reset (login)', 'color: orange;', e.message)
  }
}

// Manually call this when user log out
export async function onLogout (apolloClient) {
  localStorage.removeItem(AUTH_TOKEN)
  if (apolloClient.wsClient) restartWebsockets(apolloClient.wsClient)
  try {
    await apolloClient.resetStore()
  } catch (e) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log('%cError on cache reset (logout)', 'color: orange;', e.message)
  }
}
```

I have what I would previously use for authentication via the header here:

```js
const authMiddleware = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  // add the authorization to the headers
  const token = localStorage.getItem(AUTH_TOKEN)
  operation.setContext({
    headers: {
      authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : null
    }
  })

  return forward(operation)
})
```

It seems like when I dig a bit deeper into some of the imported objects from the vue-apollo package there is something like this already built in in the `createApolloClient` object it has this property:

```js
authLink = setContext(function (_, _ref2) {
      var headers = _ref2.headers;
      return {
        headers: _objectSpread({}, headers, {
          authorization: getAuth(tokenName)
        })
      };
    });
```

Does this mean I can simply destructure the property off the `createApolloClient` object? Any help or tips much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [vue-cli-plugin-apollo](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-cli-plugin-apollo/blob/master/generator/templates/vue-apollo/default/src/vue-apollo.js#L39-#L45)

You can pass a `link: authLink` and\or `getAuth:()=>{return "something"}` in `const defaultOptions = { ... }` in `/vue-apollo.js`.

Or in `main.js` when you call `createProvider`

```
new Vue({
  // router, store
  apolloProvider: createProvider({
    link: authLink,
    getAuth: AUTH_TOKEN => localStorage.getItem(AUTH_TOKEN)
  }),
  // ...
})
```

using both if you adding header in authLink, getAuth is probably redundant.

- if you plan to use more than one link, there is apollo-link package  `link: ApolloLink.from([ ... ])`